# Displaying filtered list in display form

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a fairly straightforward requirement that I need assistance with.

I have `List A` and `List B`. When viewing the Display Form of `List A` I want to view items of `List B` when 2 fields match. I know I can add a data view web part of List B, but I'm not sure how to filter it so it only displays the list items of the matched fields.

Note that these lists are not tied by a relationship.

Comment: You mean in the item display form of A, you want to list items from List B matching a condition?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding a `Content Query WebPart` and using `PageFieldValue`. Suppose that `List A` has column named `City`  and `List B` has column named `Location`. and that these columns can have matched values. Here are the steps to configure `Content Query WebPart`:

- Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature in Site Collection features. Now `Content Query WebPart` is available to be used.
- Got to Display form of `List A` and Edit the Page. Insert `Content Query WebPart`. It can be found in `Content Rollup Category`.
- Edit the webpart. Expand Query section and in the Source sub section select the option *Show items from following list*: Browse to `List B`.
- In the *Additional Filters section, Show items when*; select The field `City`. Then select option *is equal to* and use value `[PageFieldValue:City]`. Press Apply and and then OK

See this for more information: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/09/cqwp-pagequerystring-and-pagefieldvalue.html